# jQuery $(this) reference undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a snippet of javascript that I'm using to track form engagement. I use $(this) to pass an object to two functions in my script but my next few lines of code aren't executed because Chrome says "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Why can't I use the $(this) reference anymore?

```
$('select').blur(function () {

                var input_category = get_input_category($(this));

                var form_identifier = get_form_identifier($(this));

                if($(this).attr('name').length) {
// This is where I get the error ^^
                    var object_identifier = $(this).attr('name');
                }
                else if($(this).attr('id').length) {
                    var object_identifier = $(this).attr('id');
                }
                else if($(this).attr('class').length) {
                    var object_identifier = $(this).attr('class');
                }
                else {
                    var object_identifier = null;
                }
});
```

Edit: The select box doesn't have a name value attached.

```
                        <select type="select">
                          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                        </select>
```

But isn't that what my script looks for? If it doesn't have a name, I want it to move on. How do I check for the attribute without getting an error?

Comment: Most likely `$(this).attr('name')` is returning `undefined`. Add an `alert($(this).attr('name'))` to check if it returns a desired output.

Comment: The undefined part comes from *attr('name')*.

Comment: Does the `select` you're blurring have a name attribute defined?

Comment: Well, if it doesn't have a name then shouldn't the script just move on the next else if? That's what I'm trying to check for...

Comment: Consider doing this - $this = $(this), and reference $this wherever you need access to $(this)

Comment: Do `if($(this).attr('name'))` instead of `if($(this).attr('name').length)`

Comment: @KyleSuss Not if you try to access the property or method of the undefined object.

Comment: The selector `$('select')` will select all elements of type select (an array of objects, not a single object), this might screw up your code. If you need a special select you might want to use an id as selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was seen by Vega, the problem is on the `attr('name')` value.

Don't check the length of an object to check it's defined, because this will raise an error when there is no object on which the length could be taken.

Simply check it's defined and has a non empty value using the usual js pattern :

```
if ($(this).attr('name'))
```

instead of

```
if ($(this).attr('name').length)
```

Note that the first test checks also this isn't `""`. So there is absolutely no reason to check both that the object is defined and isn't `""`.

Comment: Well, I think he want to check if it is `undefined` as well as `''` (ex: name='')

Comment: @Vega This test does it. No need to make more complex, use the simple usual test.

Answer (score 1):

From what you said, it looks to me like you need to add few condition check.. Try below,

```
$('select').blur(function () {

    var $this = $(this);
    var input_category = get_input_category($this);
    var form_identifier = get_form_identifier($this);

    var object_identifier = null;
    if(this.name) {
        object_identifier = this.name
    } else if(this.id) {
        object_identifier = this.id
    } else if(this.className) {
        object_identifier = this.className
    } 
});
```